# Do we have any sample dialogue of stormtrooper / clone trooper 'in-battle' dialogue?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

I am wondering whether they state their rank in each statement, whether they say "Over", whether they talk in code, etc.

Comment: BLAST THEM!!!!!

Comment: I think it would be useful to specify what type of sources you're looking for, and what level of canonicity. Video games are probably the richest source for this information - for instance, the Republic Commando game gives you tons of dialogue among the titular squad. Of course, a lot of games weren't even quite canonical when they came out, and any that were canonical would be Legends now.

Comment: Outside of ANH and within the original trilogy? Good question, I don't think so.

Comment: You can literally get your answer by watching every single episode of The Clone Wars.

Comment: @thegreatjedi thanks, didn't know that, I've never watched Clone Wars.

Answer (score 5):

Does Finn count?  Because then there is an entire movie with that going on haha.

Although the stormtrooper he fights with a lightsaber calls him a traitor.

More realistic though I remember the clone troopers saying simple things like "over there" and what not in battle and the stormtroopers actually said a lot of stupid things in battle: "close the blast door!"  shortly followed by "open the blast door!"